# Parent child relation in sql table

Tags: t-sql, database-design, parent-child

I have a table in SQL that looks like

```
PID int
Season int
Markup decimal(9,2)
Name nvarchar(50)
Price decimal(9,2)
Notice nvarchar(255)
```

Since and given PID has a FK containing additional information, I want to have a new PID that could "copy/override" the existing PID, so I could use both PIDs. Basically I ended up with parent/child solution

**Solution 1**

```
PID     Season     Markup      Name     Price     Notice     ParentPID
1       2014       0.1         test1    10        notice1    1
2       2014       0.2         test2    10        notice2    1
```

In this way I can have consistency in PID numeration, but now my PK would be parentPID instead of PID to join other tables containing relevant information. PID would be just an identity column.

Is this the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Please note that primary keys have to be unique which means Parent PID can not be a primary key.

Comment: @Vulcronos what part do you don't understand?

Comment: You only have one table listed.  Foreign keys usually involve more then one table.  You also listed what you want to do, PID is an identity column, etc, then ask if this is the only way to solve a problem.  I am just not sure what problem you faced and need to be solved.

Comment: @vulcronos problem 1) parent PID cannot be parent key, since I want for search to return table1.* (rows containg PID=1, and PID=2), and I want to join them with other tables (have to join on Parent_PID!)

Comment: If you have to join on Parent_PID, that is fine if that column is the child table and points to another tables primary key.

Comment: @is there a performance downfall if you join tables on non relating columns PK-FK?

Comment: There can be in certain circumstances depending on query and dbms.  If you index the column you want to join on, that will help a lot.